# Codeigniter Ajax -Retrurning more than one row to ajax call , TWO where conditions (AND) in Select query in model file

Tags: jquery, ajax, codeigniter

when i click on the 'invoice number' in my 'purchase list' i will need to open up a collapsible table that will list the products list matching the invoice no 
I am using jquery to open up a collapsible table and Ajax to retrieve the data

MY VIEW FILE: I am using AJAX to retrieve the data

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
$(".listproduct").click(function(){
    var value = $(this).text();
$.ajax({
        type:'POST',
        url:'<?=site_url("purchasecont/getproductlist"); ?>',
        data: {'data' : value} ,
        success:function(result){

               $('#invoiceno').html(result['invoiceno']);
               $('#productname').text(result['productname']);
               $('#price').text(result['price']);


        }
    });
 $(".collapse").collapse('toggle');

});
});
</script>
```

MY CONTROLLER FILE : i will be retrieving more than one row from the table

```
public function getproductlist(){
//check if is an ajax request
if($this->input->is_ajax_request()){
    //checks if the variable data exists on the posted data
    if($this->input->post('data')){

        //query in your model you should verify if the data passed is legit before querying
         $data = $this->purchasemod->getproductlist($this->input->post('data'));
         $this->output->set_content_type('application/json');
        $this->output->set_output(json_encode($data));
        return $data;
                }
}
}
```

MY MODEL FILE : i will be retrieving more than one row from the table

```
public function getproductlist($q){
  $this->db->select('*');    
    $this->db->from('purchaseprolist');
   $this->db->where('purchaseprolist.invoice' , $q);
    $this->db->where('purchaseprolist.price != ',0,FALSE);
    $query = $this->db->get();
 foreach ($query->result() as $row)
  {
    return $row;
  }

  }
```

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: i donno if the where condition i used in my model file is correct or not!

Comment: also i am not getting the output

Comment: what is the db engine? mysql, oracle..

Comment: i am using mysql :)

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
$this->db->where('purchaseprolist.price IS NOT NULL',NULL,FALSE);
$this->db->or_where('purchaseprolist.price != ""',NULL,FALSE);
```

All others code looks ok

Final model

```
public function getproductlist($q){
    $this->db->select('*');    
    $this->db->from('purchaseprolist');
    $this->db->where('purchaseprolist.invoice' , $q);
    $this->db->where('purchaseprolist.price IS NOT NULL',NULL,FALSE);
    $this->db->or_where('purchaseprolist.price != ""',NULL,FALSE);
    $query = $this->db->get();
    return $query->row_array();
}
```

Comment: i guess that condition works because i have used it in other function before

Comment: 'price' should not be null and 'invoiceno' should match $q - this is my required condition :)

Comment: @Ramya see my updae

Comment: sorry its not happening :(

Answer (score 0):

Inside your controller you should return the processed data not `$data` variable. Try this:

```
public function getproductlist(){
    //check if is an ajax request
    if($this->input->is_ajax_request()){
        //checks if the variable data exists on the posted data
        if($this->input->post('data')){

            //query in your model you should verify if the data passed is legit before querying
           $data = $this->purchasemod->getproductlist($this->input->post('data'));
           $this->output->set_content_type('application/json');
           echo json_encode($data);
       }
    }
}
```

Also, for mysql db engine, the `were is not null` should look like this:

```
$this->db->where('purchaseprolist.price !=', null);
```

(would be `$this->db->where('purchaseprolist.price IS NOT NULL', null, false);` if oracle)

Comment: Sorry, that would be **echo json_encode($data);** there

Comment: Turns out `$this->db->where('purchaseprolist.price IS NOT NULL', null, false);` is ok for mysql too.

Comment: it is not happening is there something wrong in controller file?

Comment: try this: comment out this part: **$this->output->set_content_type('application/json');**, and replace with **echo '<pre>'.print_r($data, true),'</pre>';**

Comment: i am sorry actually i will be retrieving more than one row!

Comment: `public function getproductlist($q){
      $this->db->select('*');    
        $this->db->from('purchaseprolist');
       $this->db->where('purchaseprolist.invoice' , $q);
        $this->db->where('purchaseprolist.price != ',0,FALSE);
        $query = $this->db->get();
       foreach ($query->result() as $row)
    {
        return $row;
    }

    }`

Comment: i am not getting the result ! it is not printing anything :( is there something wrong in controller or view file ? returning the data from model file ?

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve the result in either of the two ways :

```
$this->db->where('purchaseprolist.price is NOT NULL', NULL, FALSE);
```

or

```
$where = "purchaseprolist.price is  NOT NULL";
$this->db->where($where);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$this->db->where('purchaseprolist.invoiceno' , $q);
```

i have used wrong field name ! :( sorry for the trouble :) ! i used debugging (first time ) and found it out :) thank you all